# PySimpleGUI listboxes and double-key problem

Tags: python, listbox, pysimplegui

Working with PySimpleGUI a while before, I found a problem related to how I wanted to handle my program.
I wanted my app to have language system, which worked on key system - it simply checked the language in settings file, and headed to respective language file with key provided. In such manner:

EN file:

```json
{
  "text_field_1": "Something",
  "text_field_2": "Something else",
  "text_field_3": "Something"
}
```

PL file:

```json
{
  "text_field_1": "Coś",
  "text_field_2": "Coś innego",
  "text_field_3": "Coś"
}
```

This, however, does not work ideally with PySimpleGUI listboxes, as their event/value system operates on list of single values.
So, whatever you pass onto PSG listbox, is printed out in its literal sense. This works nice for non-language-ambiguous elements (user-created content, directories, and so on), but if there's list of elements which are language-dependent, it suffers from dictionary issue - where keys cannot repeat, but values can.

Passing `lang_str(key)` functions (converting key into respective language-relative string) into the list requested by listbox feature results in, in case of our .json file from above, getting such choice:

- "Something"
- "Something else"
- "Something"

Which makes two listbox keys capable of having two the same values, because you refer to value, not the dictionary key.

Ideally, there would be separate "printed out" value which would not interact with event system, and "event" value which would be used to recognise which element was selected. But I haven't seen anything like that in PySimpleGUI.
How one can call listbox key through always-the-same dictionary key, not the value which can be ambigious?

Comment: Why you just don't update the values on the listbox, when you are changing the language? Or you don't know how to do that?

Comment: The issue I'm having is not about updating values, but that I cannot work on listbox event, having its values changing depending on language. I would need to make separate handler for every language, I assume? And it would be way easier if there was separate "printed value" and "background value", to separate what is shown and what is called in events. This is what I'm having issues with. Edited the post a bit.

Comment: Do you have any type of code? 
Also have you enabled the events on the listbox?

Comment: Provide an object for each item that will display in the language you want.  The read returns the objects, not the displayed strings.  Listbox doesn't just a list of strings as input.... also, of course, ask on the project's github.

Comment: Demo Program posted 3 days ago that shows how objects are used with Listboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of getting the values from a Listbox

- using `values['-Listbox-']` for getting the actual value
- using `sg.Listbox().get_indexes()` for getting the index of the selection

The implementation of `get_indexes()` looks like this

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

value_list = ['something', 'something else', 'something']

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(value_list, size=(30, 5), enable_events=True, key='-Listbox-')],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=(30, 1), key='-Status-')]
]

window = sg.Window('Listbox', layout, finalize=True)

listbox, status = window['-Listbox-'], window['-Status-']

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    match event:
        case sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        case 'Exit':
            break
        case '-Listbox-':
            selection = values[event]
            if selection:
                item = selection[0]
                index = listbox.get_indexes()[0]
                status.update(f'Line {index+1}, "{item}" selected')

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is OK here, just a demo code here.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

languages = {
    "English/English": "Language",
    "German/Deutsch" : "Sprache",
}
subject = {
    "English/English": ("SUBJECT for Architecture and Construction", ("Architecture", "Built Environment", "Construction", "Maintenance Services", "Planning", "Property Management", "Surveying")),
    "German/Deutsch" : ("THEMA für Architektur und Bauwesen", ("Die Architektur", "Gebaute Umwelt", "Konstruktion", "Wartungsdienstleistungen", "Planung", "Immobilienverwaltung", "Vermessung")),
}

language = "English/English"
layout = [
    [sg.Text(languages[language], expand_x=True, key="Language Text")],
    [sg.Listbox(list(subject.keys()), default_values=[language], size=(50, 5), enable_events=True, key='Language')],
    [sg.Text(subject[language][0], expand_x=True, key="Subject Text")],
    [sg.Listbox(subject[language][1], size=(50, 5), enable_events=True, key='Subject')],
]

window = sg.Window('Language', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Language':
        print(values)
        language = values[event][0]
        window["Language Text"].update(languages[language])
        window["Subject Text"].update(subject[language][0])
        window["Subject"].update(subject[language][1])
    elif event == "Subject":
        print(f'Item {window[event].get_indexes()[0]} selected !')

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're storing your data nor the language data. Here's one way using objects as items since anything can be in a list, not just strings.

> Ideally, there would be separate "printed out" value which would not interact with event system, and "event" value which would be used to recognise which element was selected.

That's what using an object gets you, a separation between the event and what's displayed.  It's up to the object to supply the display string and PySimpleGUI's event will be the object itself.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Items that are to be chosen from. Assumes each translation is part of an item
class Item():
    language = 'English'
    def __init__(self, internal, english, german_ver, french_ver):
        self.internal = internal
        self.english = english
        self.german = german_ver
        self.french = french_ver

    def __str__(self):
        return self.english if Item.language == 'English' else self.german if Item.language == 'German' else self.french

# Make the items with the translations in each language
my_item_list = [Item(f'Item {i}', f'English {i}', f'auf Deutsch {i}', f'en français {i}') for i in range(100)]

layout = [  [sg.Text('Select 1 or more items and click "Go"')],
            [sg.Listbox(my_item_list, key='-LB-', s=(20,20), select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED)],
            [sg.Combo(['English', 'German', 'French'], default_value='English', readonly=True, k='-LANG-', enable_events=True)],
            [sg.Output(s=(40,10))],
            [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Listbox Mutltiple Languages', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == '-LANG-':           # if changed languages, reload the same list so new translation will appear
        Item.language = values[event]
        window['-LB-'].update(my_item_list)
    elif event == 'Go':
        for item in values['-LB-']:
            print(item.internal)
window.close()
```